# changing html image based on passed data by python with flask

Tags: python, html, flask, web

```
return render_template('homepage.html',imgName=filenameD)
```

PYTHON

```
<img src= {{ name }} alt="something" style="width:500px;height:600px;">
```

HTML

im trying to change the image on my website based on the data I pass to it with python flask but the image does not show up, im using something called jinja?

Answer (score 1):

The image is not shown because you are referencing a non-existent variable in your template. Change your `<img>` tag to

```
<img src="{{ imgName }}" alt="something" style="width:500px;height:600px;">
```

and make sure that `filenameD` contains the *path* to your image and not only its name i.e. it should be something like `/static/image.png`.

Also, always surround your attribute values with `""` to prevent XSS attacks, see [Flask's security docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Python

```
return render_template('homepage.html',name=filename)
```

HTML

```
<img src = "{{url_for('static', filename=name) }}" alt="something" style="width:500px;height:600px;">
```

Your image must be located inside 'static' folder and named as usually ('myimg.png', etc)